# Expand/Collapse functionality best practices for a table

Tags: usability, ux-field, lean-ux

What do you think that we use instead of a checkbox to expand/collapse a table subgroup? I feel like 'checkbox' to expand wouldn't be the best practices. Image attached.[image]

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a perfect candidate for plus (+) and minus (-) icon because of the accordion nature of the ui.

See [smashing magazine](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/06/designing-perfect-accordion-checklist/) article on this design pattern.

The choice of icon doesn't matter too much as long as it's not too confusing. I think the checkbox is not the right use here because a checkbox usually denotes a boolean choice within the context of a form.